# Get text of random element from an array using C# (Selenium)

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, random, pageobjects

This is a method for my Selenium page object (the page is referred to here as "LandingPage_Page") - this method is meant to get the text of 1 element, but the trick is, that element is chosen randomly from a page that contains 12 similar elements. I want it to grab a different element from those 12 each time the test runs.

```
    public LandingPage_Page ArticleThumbnailTitle()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int rInt = r.Next(0, 11);

        var articleThumbTitle = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".row .article-title"));
        articleThumbTitle = articleThumbTitle[rInt].Text;            

        return this;
```

Everything after the final = is highlighted in red. The error says: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection"

Is articleThumbTitle an array? I want it to be... If so, am I calling the random number into the array correctly?

Thanks in advance for any guidance, 
Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect Yan,
Driver.findelements will return a list
so articleThumbTitle is an object of type list you can not assign a string text value to it. Change it like this:

```
var articleThumbTitle = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".row .article-title"));
var randomText = articleThumbTitle[rInt].Text;
```

I'd also recommend you check that articleThumbTitle.Count() < 11.

Comment: Thank YOU ! You and Akash's second edited answer both answered this for me. I was speaking to an array inappropriately, I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

You should access Text property like this :

```
 string articleThumbTitleText = articleThumbTitle[rInt].Text;
```

[Text is property](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Text.htm) defined for IWebElement. So, you can't use it as method.

Comment: Thank you Akash. However, when I remove parentheses, I get a different error. The error is no longer just for .Text; now it's a red-underline error for everything after the = (so an error on- articleThumbTitle[rInt].Text;

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<OpenQA.Selenium.WebElement>'

Comment: your articleThumbTitle seems to be of type `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<OpenQA.Se‌​lenium.WebElement>`. You need to change it as string type. I've updated post. Now, it should work

Comment: Thank you so much Akash.

Comment: I have to be honest the answer above came in first and I used tht one, but you guys were both saying the same thing essentially. I tried to accept both but it won't let me. Thanks so much again.